# In simple terms what is the difference between Fisher and Pearson kurtosis definitions?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I have read that there is a difference in kurtosis of normal distribution, but I don't quite get it intuitively. Why do two definitions exist?

Comment: Can you point to the two definitions? Is this about subtracting $3$ or about sample kurtosis estimators?

Comment: It is about subtracting 3. Interested in why is there a need for subtraction?

Comment: The fourth standardized central moment $\operatorname{E}\left[\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^4\right]$ is bounded below by $1$ and is $3$ for a normal distribution.  I would call this the *kurtosis*.  But since a normal distribution is "mesokurtic", you can subtract $3$ to give what I would call the *excess kurtosis* and say a distribution with negative excess kurtosis is "platykurtic" and one with positive of infinite excess kurtosis is "leptokurtic".   *Excess kurtosis* is more convenient working with cumulants; using *kurtosis* may be more convenient with multivariate distributions.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From comment:*

The fourth standardized central moment $\operatorname{E}\left[\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^4\right]$ is bounded below by $1$ and is $3$ for a normal distribution. I would call this the *kurtosis*.

But since a normal distribution is "mesokurtic", you can subtract $3$ to give what I would call the *excess kurtosis* and say a distribution with negative excess kurtosis is "platykurtic" and one with positive of infinite excess kurtosis is "leptokurtic".

Excess kurtosis is more convenient working with cumulants; using kurtosis may be more convenient with multivariate distributions.

Comment: Could you kindly edit your answer to specify which one is Pearson and which one is Fisher kurtosis definition?

Comment: @sage One site says [Pearson kurtosis](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/p/p157.htm) is $\beta_2\equiv \frac{\mu_4}{\sigma^4}$ so what I call kurtosis, and says [Fisher kurtosis](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/p/p183.htm) is $\gamma_2\equiv b_2\equiv\frac{\mu_4}{\sigma^4}-3$ so what I call excess kurtosis.  But if you look at Pearson's first recorded use of "kurtosis" in *Das Fehlergesetz und Seine Verallgemeinerungen Durch Fechner und Pearson. A Rejoinder* in 1905 then he says "the degree of kurtosis $(\beta_2-3)$" so I would not attribute this way

Comment: Something went wrong with one of my links which for Fisher kurtosis should have been https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/f/f183.htm